# mysql2 destroy error

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql2

I'm trying to destroy an object using a call similar to

```
MyObject.destroy_all({:user_id => current_user.id, :item_type_id => params[:type_id], :item_id => params[:item_id]})
```

Rails generates this as a SQL commands:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
MyObject Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `my_objects`.* FROM `my_objects` WHERE `my_objects`.`user_id` = 1 AND `my_objects`.`item_type_id` = 3 AND `my_objects`.`item_id` = 9
(0.1ms)  BEGIN 
SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM `my_objects` WHERE `my_objects`.`` = NULL
```

The last SQL Statement causes this error (which makes sense)

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'my_objects.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `my_objects` WHERE `my_objects`.`` = NULL
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Rails 3.2.1
mysql2 0.3.11
mysql 5 (I think)

Comment: Does the `my_objects` table have a primary key? It looks like Rails doesn't know which column identifies each `my_objects` record.